# I always fails when compiling WebKit , OS : Windows10 1809 x64

Tags: python, perl, browser, webkit

1).Before compiling WebKit, I reinstalled Windows 10. The terminal I used when 
   compiling it was PowerShell.

2).The guide I use is here: https://webkit.org/webkit-on-windows/,I did not 
   install cygwin.
   In addition, I set up two environment variables in accordance with another
   guide: WEBKIT_LIBRARIES & WEBKIT_OUTPUTDIR. This guide is here: 
   https://webkit.org/building-webkit-on-windows

3).The main problem is that when I run "perl build-webkit" in powershell, 
   it will report an error:
   "Free to wrong pool 1b8e80 not 9504a10099d76a14 at
    C:/Perl64/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 2739.
    Can't spawn "perl Tools/Scripts/update-webkit-support-libs": No such file
    or directory at build-webkit line 257.
    Died at build-webkit line 257."

and every time I run this command, I will receive almost the same error, for 
   example, I just ran it again.Then the error is as follows:
   "Free to wrong pool e38e80 not 95054c000387c36b at
    C:/Perl64/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 2739.
    Can't spawn "perl Tools/Scripts/update-webkit-support-libs": No such
    file or directory at build-webkit line 257.
    Died at build-webkit line 257."

4). I tried to solve my problem through Google search, but I didn't find any 
    useful content, so give me some help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by running the command "perl build-webkit -- skip-library-update" in PowerShell.
It's better to download and extract WebKitAuxiliaryLibrary.zip and WebKitSupportLibrary.zip to the right location first, and then build-webkit.

Comment: --------By questioner

Answer (score 1):

You can start powershell as user or as administrator. I'll suggest, you retry executing as administrator. If you are a regular user or logged on as admin, it's not the same than the right mousebutton to find the right way.

Be sure, that you have all scripts. Maybe, that your archive is buggy.

Comment: thanks,I have been running powershell as an administrator.I tried to compile WebKit two months ago, but I have the same problem as now,so I switched to cygwin for compilation, but after compiling, I couldn't run Minibrowser. The system prompts that I can't find a dll file that exists in the directory. I have the same problem when compiling again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its useful, to place the dll into the system32 directory. I think, that in your case, the mistake is in assiciation. You have both on Win10x64, the x86 and x64 dll's.

I'll suggest, that you try to build on a win7 x86 win32 first. Second step should a contact to the mozilla webkit team.

My experience of Cygwin was a very short one. It's like a toy without battery.

Comment: thanks, the problem has been solved. and my webkit release has been compiled successfully. I added the option "--skip-library-update" when i ran build-webkit :)